# sequelize handling rejection in the create statement - catch not firing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The sequelize create statement has an error and I would like to handle that error. Since the create statement has the error I need to handle promise rejection. How do I do that in code? Tried to look at the sequelize documents but unable to work it out.

```
db.Employee.create(empData, 
{
    include:[
        {
            model: db.EmployeeDetails
        }
    ]
}).then(function(newEmployee){
    res.json(newEmployee);
}).catch(function(err){
    return next(err);
});
```

The error is on the create and so the webpage just gives an internal server error. I was under the impression that the catch was something that handled the promise rejection and failure. In this case, how can I handle the promise rejection in code. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you get promise as reulst of this function then catch should be enough to get all erros happen in it. But it could be that error happens in separate context, then catch will not help.

Comment: in express you can use their error-handing http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Can you please give details about the error? stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `next(err)`, by default, you send a `500 Internal Server Error` message. If you use Express, and want to show a custom error, just append a status code which is not `5xx` to the error:

**General Usage**:

```
const err = new Error("my custom error")
err.statusCode = 400
next(err)
```

In your snippet, do:

```
db.Employee.create(empData, {
    include:[
        {
            model: db.EmployeeDetails
        }
    ]
}).then(function(newEmployee){
    res.json(newEmployee);
}).catch(function(err){
    err.statusCode = 400
    next(err);
});
```

If you haven't set your error handler in Express you will need to add somewhere at the end of the main file this:

```
// Error Handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err)
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  let msg = err.message
  // Do not expose 500 error messages in production, to the client
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && err.statusCode === 500) {
     msg = "Internal Server Error"
  }
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(msg)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage showing a 500 error means the issue was caught / working as intended. What you need to do is figure out how to handle displaying that error in a pretty format - this being a UI task. If you want a 'patch' for hiding the issue, change your return to a res. This will trick your browser with a 200 status and hide the error.

I do want to add, I recommend trying async/await for sequelize. There's a good amount of usage examples with it.

**Promise**

```
db.Employee.create(empData, 
{
    include:[
        {
            model: db.EmployeeDetails
        }
    ]
}).then(function(newEmployee){
    res.json(newEmployee);
}).catch(function(err){
    // Temporary patch
    res.json("pretty error message");
});
```

**Async/Await version**

```
async function createEmployee(empData) {
  try {
    return await db.Employee.create(empData, {
      include:[ { model: db.EmployeeDetails } ]
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle error here
    return err;
  }
}
```